Does `unbind()` return the views of tensors in PyTorch?
The doc of unbind() just says below:

Returns a tuple of all slices along a given dimension, already without it.

So, does it mean that unbind() returns (a tuple of) the views of tensors instead of (a tuple of) the copies of tensors?
import torch

my_tensor = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 2, 3],
                          [4, 5, 6, 7],
                          [8, 9, 10, 11]])
torch.unbind(input=my_tensor)
# (tensor([0, 1, 2, 3]),
#  tensor([4, 5, 6, 7]),
#  tensor([8, 9, 10, 11]))

Actually, there are the similar functions split(), vsplit(), hsplit(), tensor_split() and chunk(), then their docs say they return the views of tensors while the doc of unbind() just says the slices of tensors.
So again, does unbind() return the views of tensors?

Unbind returns a view. You can check this by looking at the data pointers of the unbind result. You can also mutate the original tensor and see the unbind result is also mutated
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
y = torch.unbind(x)

# check data pointers are the same
for i in range(len(y)):
    assert x[i].data_ptr() == y[i].data_ptr()

# mutate data of x
x.data[0] = torch.tensor([10,11,12])

# y[0] is also mutated
assert x[0] == y[0]

print(y[0])
> tensor([10, 11, 12])


Maybe for completeness: The PyTorch doc lists unbind() as a function that returns views (scroll down to "For reference, here’s a full list of view ops in PyTorch"). Also, maybe less explicitly, the unbind() doc states "Returns a tuple of all slices …" – and (basic) slicing results are always views in PyTorch.
